# How to store each iteration of a for loop in an array? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

The code below echos out the multiples of 3 & 5 below 20. Please how can I store these values in an array as the loop iterates?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
        if ($i % 3 == 0 || $i % 5 == 0 ) {
          $mul = $i;
          echo "{$mul}, ";
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize the array.  With PHP 5.4, you can do `$arr = [];` whereas with earlier versions of PHP, you have to do `$arr = array();`.
2. Run `array_push($arr, $mul)` where $arr is the array and $mul is the value

Without further ado, the code:

```
<?php

$result = []; 
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
  if ($i % 3 == 0 || $i % 5 == 0 ) {
    array_push($result, $i);
  }
}
print_r($result);

?>
```